# Find groups that do not contain any NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions

I have a many to many table called dbo.ObjectOwner having following columns:

```
ObjectId |  OwnerId | StartDate |EndDate
```

Where ObjectId, OwnerId is not a primary key and Startdate and Enddate refer to the dates where Object is owned by Owner.

The query I'm trying to do should return all 
ObjectId's where for each ObjectId, it has no associated records where EndDate is null. I.e, return all objects who currently have no owner.

so something like

```
foreach(objectId in dbo.ObjectOwner)
if ( 
        doesnotexist (records where ObjectId = objectid and EndDate is null)
   )
{
   add this objectid to the select table
}
```

I had a look at group by and having, but the following script returns all records

```
SELECT oo.ObjectId
FROM    dbo.ObjectOwner oo
GROUP BY oo.ObjectId
HAVING NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    dbo.ObjectOwner
    WHERE   dbo.ObjectOwner.EndDate = null
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe it would be more clear if you add sample data and expected result

Comment: @skeffin see revised answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`. The following works because `NULL` values are not `COUNT`ed:

```
SELECT ObjectId
FROM ObjectOwner
GROUP BY ObjectId
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(EndDate)
```

Comment: I think this selects the records that have null end dates...the OP wants records that don't.

Comment: actually...bummer...that won't work either...as most records (old ownership records) fit the bill.

Comment: Yes - so sorry...yer right ;-) I was still thinking in terms of sans-group-by.

Answer (score 2):

It can't work if you write <...> = NULL, because NULL can't be equal to something.

```
SELECT oo.ObjectId
FROM    dbo.ObjectOwner oo
GROUP BY oo.ObjectId
HAVING NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT  1
    FROM    dbo.ObjectOwner
    WHERE   dbo.ObjectOwner.EndDate IS NULL
)
```

Comment: This returns no records at all- I'll admit I'm confused as to why this doesn't work

Comment: I can help you, give me a db fiddle with your data and this query.